# Problem for Flutter infinite scroll pagination for ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, pagination

I am building a paginated infinite scrolling list in Flutter and used the following code:

```
...
final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
...
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ...
    ...
      _getNotification(userInfo.id!, reset: true);
      addItems(userInfo.id!);
  }

Future<void> _getNotification(int userInfoId, {bool reset = false}) async {
    await _notificationController.getNotifications(
      userInfoId,
      queryString: "",
      pageSize: _pageSize,
    );
  }

Future<void> addItems(int userId) async {
    _controller.addListener(() async {
      if (_controller.position.maxScrollExtent <= _controller.position.pixels) {
        if (_notificationController.currentPage <
            _notificationController.totalPages) {
          _notificationController.currentPage++;
          await _getNotification(userId);
          // _isLoading(false);
        }
      }
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
   Expanded(
                    child: Obx(() {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          controller: _controller,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                          physics:
                              _notificationController.status.value.isLoading
                                  ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
                                  : const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount:
                              _notificationController.status.value.isLoading &&
                                      _notificationController.currentPage == 0
                                  ? _pageSize
                                  : _notificationController
                                      .entity.value.notifications.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            notifications.Notification? notificationValue;

                            if (index <
                                _notificationController
                                    .entity.value.notifications.length) {
                              notificationValue = _notificationController
                                  .entity.value.notifications[index];
                            }
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 82,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      notificationValue != null
                                          ? '$index - sendDate: ${notificationValue.sendDate.toString()}'
                                          : '',
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      notificationValue != null
                                          ? 'name: ${notificationValue.notificationCategory!.name.toString()}'
                                          : '',
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      notificationValue != null
                                          ? 'message: ${notificationValue.message.toString()}'
                                          : '',
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                    }),
                  ),
...
```

Everything seems to be going ok, but the problem happens when I pull down on the last item and I get this error:

> The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for _StretchController:
> Build scheduled during frame.

I tried looking for something to fix it but I couldn't find anything...

Help...